# Possible to log into another Windows account using "SQL Server Authentication"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

If I want to log into a SQL Server instance using another Windows account can I do this by simply selecting "SQL Server Authentication" as my authentication mode and entering the `DOMAIN/username` and `password` for the account I want to use?

Are there any special settings that I need to set in order to get this to work?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible. What you can do though, is run your application or whatever is accessing the database under a different user context.

Comment: Only way I ever got this to work was to right-click on SSMS and run as other account and provide those credentials.

Comment: I think this may be a duplicate question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/849149/connect-different-windows-user-in-sql-server-management-studio-2005-or-later

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. 'SQL Server Authentication' works only with SQL Server logins, it won't work with a NT login. To log in as another credential have the process run as the credential you desire to run as. Use [`runas`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true), most likely you want to run SSMS like this:

```
runas /netonly /user:domain\user "c:\program files\...\ssms.exe"
```

By specifying the `/netonly` argument your SSMS will run with the desired NT credential *only* for remote hosts, locally will have your local credentials. This not only preserves your SSMS environment (last used files, options etc) and doesn't require `domain\user` to have local priviledges, but, more importantly, it works even for a **completely unrelated domain**. That is if you machine is in domain `foo` (or not even joined to the domain) and the desired runas is in domain `bar`, the `runas /netonly /user:bar\user ...` will run just fine.

The `/netonly` trick works only if the SQL server host you are connecting to is remote (not on the same machine). If is local, then your `runas` must be locally using the desired credential, so remove the `/netonly` argument.

Comment: I use this all the time. runas is a lifesaver. Also just disregard that the windows authentication box wherever you connect will display your -local- computer/user, but in reality it uses the specified domain and username.

Comment: FYI, we use this method and it works great. However, it can cause havoc on Outlook and other domain reliant software. Not sure why, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 7, you can add credentials for other domains via Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Credential Manager. Map your credentials to each server you want to log into.

Then, log into additional machines using Windows Authentication. I think there is a caveat - it will try to log you in to the server using your current domain/username. IF that is rejected, it will lookup any entries you have for that server in Credential Manager, and if those are valid, you will be logged in.

Answer (score -2):

If I understand the question correctly, the solution it just ship + Right click on your SSMS, that will give you "connect as different user" option and that where you want to put your windows authentication. Domain\User and password.