# How to find SQL Server running port?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, connection-string

Yes I read this [How to find the port for MS SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518823/how-to-find-the-port-for-ms-sql-server-2008)

no luck.

> telnet 1433

returns connection failed, so I must specify other port.

I tried to use

> netstat -abn

but I don't see sqlservr.exe or something similar on this list.

Why it so difficult to find that port? :/

Comment: Did you check if the Sql Server **Service** is running?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Try this:

```
USE master
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on' 
GO
```

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2495/identify-sql-server-tcp-ip-port-being-used/

Comment: did u try using master db and runnig this

Comment: If it returns 0 rows TCP/IP is disabled. Enabled TCP/IP in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Just to add - in recent versions it seems TCP is disabled by default in the Developer Edition, while UDP is on.

Answer (score 83):

This is the one that works for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    local_tcp_port 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
WHERE local_tcp_port IS NOT NULL
```

(this assumes you're connected with SSMS remotely over TCP, not with SSMS on the local machine with named pipes)

Comment: See also https://gist.github.com/ststeiger/5f1f8af65023bd751252c4913d9e4175

Answer (score 82):

very simple. 
make a note of the sqlsrvr.exe PID from taskmanager
then run this command:

```
netstat -ano | findstr *PID*
```

it will show TCP and UDP connections of your SQL server (including ports)
standard is 1433 for TCP and 1434 for UDP

example :
 [image]

Comment: This worked for me "in reverse": needed to find (non-default) port number of remote machine that I was connected to in SSMS.

Answer (score 60):

If you can start the Sql Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Your instance > TCP/IP > Properties

[image]

Answer (score 8):

If you have run "netstat -a -b -n" (from an elevated command prompt) and you don't see "sqlservr.exe" at all then either your SQL Server service is not running or its TCP/IP network library is disabled.

Run SQL Server Configuration Manager (Start | All Programs | Microsoft SQL Server 2008 | Configuration Tools).

Navigate to SQL Server Services.
In the right-hand pane look for SQL Server (). Is it stopped? If so, start it.

Navigate to SQL Server Network Configuration (or SQL Server Network Configuration (32-bit) as appropriate) then Protocols for .
In the right-hand pane look for "TCP/IP". Is it disabled? If so, enable it, then restart the SQL Server service.

Note that he Instance ID will be MSSQLSERVER for the default instance.

Please also note that you don't have to enable the TCP/IP network library to connect a client to the service. Clients can also connect through the Shared Memory network library (if the client is on the same machine) or the Named Pipes network library.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to look in SQL Server Management (sqlservermanager15.msc), then run this query in the database, e.g. from sqlcmd or ssms:

```
SELECT * FROM [sys].[dm_tcp_listener_states]
```

| listener_id | ip_address | is_ipv4 | port | type | type_desc | state | state_desc | start_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ::1 | False | 1433 | 0 | TSQL | 0 | ONLINE | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000 |
| 2 | 127.0.0.1 | True | 1433 | 0 | TSQL | 0 | ONLINE | 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000 |

Thanks to @vladimir-bashutin for pointing out this one. Here is another one:

```sql
SELECT [name]
  ,[protocol_desc]
  ,[type_desc]
  ,[state]
  ,[state_desc]
  ,[is_admin_endpoint]
FROM [master].[sys].[endpoints]
```

| name | protocol_desc | type_desc | state | state_desc | is_admin_endpoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TSQL Local Machine | SHARED_MEMORY | TSQL | 0 | STARTED | False |
| TSQL Named Pipes | NAMED_PIPES | TSQL | 0 | STARTED | False |
| TSQL Default TCP | TCP | TSQL | 0 | STARTED | False |
| TSQL Default VIA | VIA | TSQL | 0 | STARTED | False |

So now you have the port and protocol. If you don't have access to these system tables, consider using an SSRP client, such as https://github.com/adzm/ssrpc.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's not using TCP/IP

Have a look at the SQL Server Configuration Manager to see what protocols it's using.

Comment: SQL Native Client config? TCP/IP is Enabled. But default port is set to 1433 :/

Comment: @keram No - that's for clients. You want the server configuration utiltiy.

Comment: where I can find that config?

Comment: On the start menu - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174212(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 3):

try once:-

```
USE master
DECLARE       @portNumber   NVARCHAR(10)
EXEC   xp_instance_regread
@rootkey    = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
@key        =
'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IpAll',
@value_name = 'TcpDynamicPorts',
@value      = @portNumber OUTPUT
SELECT [Port Number] = @portNumber
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

This is another script that I use:

```
-- Find Database Port script by Jim Pierce  09/05/2018

USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @DynamicportNo NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @StaticportNo NVARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @ConnectionportNo INT;

-- Look at the port for the current connection
SELECT @ConnectionportNo = [local_tcp_port]
 FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
    WHERE session_id = @@spid;

-- Look for the port being used in the server's registry
EXEC xp_instance_regread @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
                        ,@key =
                         'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IpAll'
                        ,@value_name = 'TcpDynamicPorts'
                        ,@value = @DynamicportNo OUTPUT

EXEC xp_instance_regread @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE'
                        ,@key =
                         'Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp\IpAll'
                        ,@value_name = 'TcpPort'
                        ,@value = @StaticportNo OUTPUT

SELECT [PortsUsedByThisConnection] = @ConnectionportNo
      ,[ServerStaticPortNumber] = @StaticportNo
      ,[ServerDynamicPortNumber] = @DynamicportNo
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from sys.dm_tcp_listener_states
```

More there:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tcp-listener-states-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Comment: While this link may assist in your answer to the question, you can improve this answer by taking vital parts of the link and putting it into your answer, this makes sure your answer is still an answer if the link gets changed or removed :)

Answer (score 2):

In our enterprise I don't have access to MSSQL Server, so I can'r access the system tables.

What works for me is:

1. capture the network traffic `Wireshark` (run as Administrator, select Network Interface),while opening connection to server.
2. Find the ip address with `ping`
3. filter with `ip.dst == x.x.x.x`

The port is shown in the column `info` in the format `src.port -> dst.port`

Answer (score 1):

Try to enable the protocol by:
**Configuration Manger** > **SQL server Network Configuration** > **Protocols for MSSQLSERVER** > properties of **TCP/IP**

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2000 
   Programs |
   MS SQL Server |
   Client Network Utility |
   Select TCP_IP then Properties

SQL Server 2005
   Programs |
   SQL Server |
   SQL Server Configuration Manager |
   Select Protocols for MSSQLSERVER or select Client Protocols and right click on TCP/IP

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the best options but just another way is to read the Windows Registry in the host machine, on elevated PowerShell prompt you can do something like this:

```
#Get SQL instance's Port number using Windows Registry:
$instName = (Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server').InstalledInstances[0]
$tcpPort = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$instName\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp").TcpPort
Write-Host The SQL Instance:  `"$instName`"  is listening on `"$tcpPort`"  "TcpPort."
```

[image]
Ensure to run this PowerShell script in the Host Server (that hosts your SQL instance / SQL Server installation), which means you have to first RDP into the SQL Server/Box/VM, then run this code.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

From PowerShell you can use this to see what port your instance is using:

You can change `MSSQLSERVER` to your own instance name.

```
$wmi = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Wmi.ManagedComputer' localhost
$tcp = $wmi.ServerInstances['MSSQLSERVER'].ServerProtocols['Tcp']
$ipAll = $tcp.IPAddresses | where { $_.Name -eq "IPAll" }
write-host ($ipAll.IPAddressProperties.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the server was remote and used a named instance. The SQL Browse Service is what will translate that into a port for the client. Just make a connection through SQL Management Studio. Perform an nslookup of the server name to obtain its IP. Then do a:

```
netstat -ano | findstr {ip}
```

Should have a few remote connections in the list all using the same port number. If the server is configured to use dynamic ports then this will change.