# How to Identify port number of SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Install SQL server in my system and I have to check on which port number  SQL is working in my system

Comment: The default port for SQL is 1433, have you checked that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find SQL Server running port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port)

Answer (score 98):

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio
2. Connect to the database engine for which you need the port number
3. Run the below query against the database

   `select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port from sys.dm_exec_connections where local_net_address is not null`

The above query shows the local IP as well as the listening Port number

Comment: This query can also be executed in `sqlcmd`.

Comment: Didn't return any rows.

Comment: @trilawney If you are connecting to the database locally it won't return any rows. You will have to connect to the database remotely. When you connect locally it uses shared memory to connect, when you connect remotely it connects through TCP.

Comment: Thanks Punter. That was helpful. I figured it out using netstat -abn

Comment: @Punter015.. my sys is not having this table. Does it have any other name as well. M getting error with the query:      "mysql> select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port from sys.dm_exec_connections where local_net_address is not null;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'sys.dm_exec_connections' doesn't exist"

Comment: @YashiSrivastava, This query is for Microsoft SQL Server. You can use "SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'port'" for MySQL. For more information on  show variables refer, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html

Comment: This is the chicken! We couldn't work out why we couldn't connect to a co-worker's SQL Server on his laptop. Turned out it's running in shared memory not TCP/IP. doh!

Answer (score 44):

You can also use this query

`USE MASTER
GO
xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on'
GO`

Source : [sqlauthority blog](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/15/sql-server-find-port-sql-server-is-listening-port-sql-server-is-running/)

Comment: This should be the answer. Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: No rows for me SQL Server Express 15.0.2000

Comment: This works on SQL Server Express 2019

Answer (score 42):

1. Open Run in your system.
2. Type `%windir%\System32\cliconfg.exe`
3. Click on ok button then check that the "TCP/IP Network Protocol Default Value Setup" pop-up is open.
4. Highlight TCP/IP under the Enabled protocols window.
5. Click the Properties button.
6. Enter the new port number, then click OK.

[image]

Comment: This caused my SQL Server Management Studio to malfunction (due to a null number bug in Visual Studio 2010). It was able to connect and list tables, as well as open an edit 200 rows view, but failed to open a new query window.

Comment: @Ankit Jain: Can you explain what this does? If this is changing the server config, then what are the side-effects of the said change?

Answer (score 24):

Visually you can open "SQL Server Configuration Manager" and check properties of "Network Configuration":

[image: SQL Server Configuration]

Comment: What does Enabled = No mean? I have values defined from IP1 to IP8, but for all of them Enabled = No is set.

Answer (score 9):

This query works for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    local_tcp_port 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
WHERE local_tcp_port IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: just blank for me

Answer (score 8):

To check all the applications listening on all ports, there is command:

```
netstat -ntpl
```

Comment: On Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7 I need to use `netstat -ap TCP` to display listening (and connected) TCP ports

Comment: This is the only way I could find to get the port number from the client side, without the ability to RDP into the server, or run administrative stored procs. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

PowerShell solution that shows all of the instances on the host as well as their incoming traffic addresses. The second bit might be helpful if all you know is the DNS:

```
ForEach ($SQL_Proc in Get-Process | Select-Object -Property ProcessName, Id | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -like "*SQL*"})
{
    Get-NetTCPConnection | `
     Where-Object {$_.OwningProcess -eq $SQL_Proc.id} | `
      Select-Object -Property `
                                @{Label ="Process_Name";e={$SQL_Proc.ProcessName}}, `
                                @{Label ="Local_Address";e={$_.LocalAddress + ":" + $_.LocalPort }},  `
                                @{Label ="Remote_Address";e={$_.RemoteAddress + ":" + $_.RemotePort}}, State | `
      Format-Table
}
```

Comment: This worked great. Would be nice if it could somehow include the instance name.