# Adding JPA-Connection in Eclipse

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, jpa, connection

After 5 hours of trying and not finding any solution to my problem, maybe you guys can help me. I´ve been trying to add a database connection to my eclipse JPA-project, but the window in Eclipse won´t let me pass on:

[image]

I am using Eclipse Link 2.5.2 and JPA 2.1 with the newest Eclipse Neon release, my Database is an MSSQL-Server 2012. I have implemented a JDBC connection, which  works just fine (to make sure the Server-Ports are open and the connection-URL etc. is correct).

If i want to add a new connection with **new**->**other**->**Connection Profiles**->**Connection Profile** in my JPA-Project. Eclipse lets me choose the **Connection Profile Type** where I select **SQL Server**, then I define a new Driver with **New Driver Definition**, where I take **Microsoft SQL Server 2012 JDBC Driver**, add the sqljdbc4.jar (which is located in my lib folder and added to the build path). Lastly I add the connection URL and the other preferences. After I click **OK**, I cannot move on from there because the buttons are disabled. Did anyone experienced the same problem or knows a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

Do not use "Microsoft SQL Server ..." driver (there seems to be a bug here in Eclipse, as I tested the same procedure w/ MySQL & it worked just fine), so instead use "Generic JDBC Driver"

1. Type in name (& optional description)
2. Edit driver definition (Click on triangle icon)

   - 2.1 Jar List tab - Add in path to the driver jar file
   - 2.2 Properties tab -

     - 2.2.1 - Connection URL : jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:50147  (MS Sql Server does not necessarily use the default port 1443 & allocates a listening port dynamically - see [How to Identify port number of SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451490/how-to-identify-port-number-of-sql-server) (#2) for how to determine which port is being used)
     - 2.2.2 - Database name :  "Your database name"
     - 2.2.3 - Driver class : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
     - 2.2.4 - UserID  :  "myuserid"
     - 2.2.5 - Password :

After this the "Test Connection" button is active & can be clicked & returns "Ping succeeded!".

I also had to do the below 3 things for MS Sql Server :
(My windows authentication login i.e. domain\login did not work)

1. In SQL Server Configuration Manager - Enable *ALL* TCP/IP protocols for

   - 1.1 SQL Native Client Configuration / Client Protocols, and,
   - 1.2 SQL Server Network Configuration / Protocols for SQLEXPRESS
     (Apparently TCP/IP was disable by default for my MS Sql Server)
2. In MS Sqlserver Mgmt Studio, in Object Explorer

   - 1.1 Under Security - Create a new login "myuserid" (password : ) & assign appropriate default db, etc. to it
   - 1.2 Under "Your database name" - Create a new user "myuserid" & assign this user to the login "myuserid" above
3. In MS Sqlserver Mgmt Studio, in Object Explorer
   Under "Your datatbase name", rt. click, "Properties" | "Permissions" | "View Server Permissions" | "Security" | "Server Authentication" - select "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode".  Restart the SQL Server.

Press the "Test Connection" button & it'll say "Ping Succeeded!"  This can also be done in Eclipse's Database perspective (for create a new connection) as the same setup windows are used there as well.

Answer (score 4):

The JPA has a problem with the connection of the driver that you are using, but it works very well with the JBDC 2008 driver, I recommend you to use it and try it.

[image]

Then you can quietly make the respective settings for your connection to the database you want.