# C# - Can't access data from a simple, 1-table mdf database that I have just created with another Visual Studio 2015 program

Tags: c#, linq, mdf

From the program that created the file (DB_Write), I am able to access and query the data easily. I wanted to see if I could read the file and manipulate the data from another simple C# program (DB_Read).  DB_Read is able to find the database with the connectionString and open the connection successfully but my statement, "var DatabaseExists = context.data.Any(); fails ever time.  I've spent days searching the net for some clue but without success, which makes me think that I am overlooking something very simple and obvious.  DB_Read is made up of parts that I cut and pasted directly from DB_Write (database class, database context and column names). I've include the full program below. What am I missing here?

...

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace DB_Read
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }
   

    public class TestDB
    {
       [Key]public int Index { get; set; }
         
        public string Letter { get; set; }

        public Double WTime { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestDB_Context : DbContext
    {
       public DbSet<TestDB> data { get; set; }
    }


    private void btnSum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string connectionString; 

       SqlConnection cnn;

       connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;
                            Initial Catalog=DB_Write.Form1+TestDB_Context;
                            Integrated Security=True";

       cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

       cnn.Open();

       using (var context = new TestDB_Context())
       {
          var DatabaseExists = context.data.Any();

          if(DatabaseExists == true)
          {
             var query = (from column3 in context.data
                          select column3.WTime).Sum();

             txtResult.Text = Convert.ToString(query);
          }
       }

       cnn.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

...

Comment: `fails ever time`  It would help if you tell us what the failure is.  This line looks weird: `Initial Catalog=DB_Write.Form1+TestDB_Context`

Comment: Your context isn't even using that connection string.

Comment: The following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425) shows how one can verify the name of one's SQL server instance.

Comment: Sorry Lars - in retrospect, that line should have said, "DatabaseExists = context.data.Any()" returns FALSE every time.  If I comment out that line and let the query execute, I get the dreaded, "The cast to value type 'System.Double' failed because the materialized value is null.  Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must be a nullable type."

The database has data in every column and every line and the DB_Write program that produced the database has this exact query which works every time.

The connectionString is copied/pasted from Server Explorer - Properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SqlConnection` (cnn) is doing nothing.  It's not being used by anything.

you should have something like

```
public class TestDB_Context : DbContext
{
   public TestDB_Context(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) 
   {}

   public DbSet<TestDB> data { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
private void btnSum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string connectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;
                        Initial Catalog=DB_Write.Form1+TestDB_Context;
                        Integrated Security=True";

   using (var context = new TestDB_Context(connectionString))
...
```

Comment: James and Lars - Programming Alchemists who just turned lead into gold!  I really appreciate the fact that you have taken time to share your wisdom, experience and knowledge with a relative new comer to the vast C# universe.