# VB.Net Connection string over draytek tunneling vpn

Tags: string, vb.net, connection, vpn

I am doing a VB.NET application, using SQL server as my database. SQL sever is located on other network connected via draytek VPN Matcher, Can you please recommend, what is the best connection string to connect to SQL Server from windows form application using oledb

Thanks to all

I tried using the IP directly with port 1433. I could connect through SSMS but not by the VB.Net application. I tried the SSMS it connects, but my appliction do not connect. It gives Error, server is not available any more.

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.