# Connect SQL Server using .NET MAUI and perform CRUD operations

Tags: c#, sql-server, maui

I'm need some guidance on how to connect .NET MAUI with my local SQL Server database. I've been using C# WinForms and SQL Server for a while now, but I'm not sure how to proceed with .NET MAUI.

My goal is to perform some CRUD operations from an Android emulator to my local SQL Server database. I'd really appreciate any advice on how to achieve this. If I need to write an API for this scenario, I'd love some help with that as well.

I have tried connect the SQL Server database directly `using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;` but it works only on windows machine, but not in android emulator.

Comment: You should never connect directly to a db server from a mobile client.  Use a web service as an intermediate layer to protect your db.  That said, please search before posting.  This topic has been discussed many times

Comment: @Jason Never is a strong word :) But in the general case I 100% agree.

Comment: The word "local" has different meaning when speaking in the context of android emulators. The deal is that your windows machine itself has the server, and your android is machine inside that machine. If you posted some code... Anyway, what Jason told you is right. If you are not writing server browser app, this is serious mistake. Make new ASP WEB API, and edit the Weather Forecast code to get data from sql server. As a starting point...

Comment: if you are only using the Maui windows target, then directly accessing Sql is perfectly valid. of course, if you are only using a window target, then you probably shouldn't be using Maui. :)

Comment: When the app is finished, do you expect SQL Server to run on the android device? Because that's _not gonna happen_. Or do you expect to run the emulator all the time? Because that seems like you're making things a lot harder than they need to be.

Answer (score 1):

As someone said, usually you don't call it directly for security reasons. But If yo are just looking to test then you can do it just like you do it locally:

Write a service for retrieving an object:

```
public static class UserService
{
    private const string server = "";
    private const string database = "";
    private const string username = "";
    private const string password = "";

    private static string connectionString => $"Data Source={server};Database={database};User Id={username};Password={password}";

    public static async Task<UserDto> GetUserAsync(string username, string password, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column = @value";
            return await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<UserDto>(sql).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your button call just call the service:

```
var user = UserService.GetUserAsync("John Doe", "abcd1234");
```

---

### Note

If you are running an app on an anroid emulator you either have to provide the actual server IP plus SQL instance name you are trying to connect to.

However, if you are trying to connect to a local database you CANNOT use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. These simply will not work. What you CAN do however, is use the special alias port specifically for android emulators `10.0.2.2` to connect to the computer the emulator is running on.

Comment: Probably won't work - one has to specify to use TCP and may need to configure one's firewall. See the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425

Comment: Isn't there some additional setup step needed, so that the Android emulator (which is on a virtual machine) can reach  the PC?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve yes and no. If the server name is correct nothing more needs to be done. But when you connect locally yo ucannot use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` You have to use a special alias IP for local connections, which is `10.0.2.2`

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid `SqlConnection` is an TCP/IP connection. As mentioned on the other comment and updated post, you should be able to connect to any database with just that if the IP is correct - but have to use `10.0.2.2` instead of `localhost` which is a special alias port for android emulators.

Answer (score 0):

To get data from a server, you will likely need to implement authentication so that random users cannot access it. Here is a sample project that demonstrates how to do this with a free DevExpress WebAPI service: [Role-based Access Control (RBAC) & Permission Management](https://docs.devexpress.com/MAUI/404316/scenarios/role-based-data-access)

You may also consider implementing a local copy of your data in SQLite so that application can be used offline. In general, proper CRUD implementation involves several steps from database binding to constraints validation. While it's difficult to describe all details in this answer, you may find the following blog post useful: [.NET MAUI — Incorporate CRUD Operations in Your Mobile App with DevExpress CollectionView](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/mobile/archive/2023/10/18/incorporate-crud-operations-into-your-app-with-devexpress-net-maui-collectionview.aspx)

It describes how to implement CRUD with SQLite & Entity Framework Core in a .NET MAUI application. Additionally, it includes a [GitHub example](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/maui-collection-view/tree/23.1.3%2B/CS/CrudOperations) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE4pRxMiuaI).

Answer (score 0):

So, in the beginning there was no Maui, There was Xamarin Forms an it did not allow you to connect to a SQLServer AT ALL without an intermediary Service. I chose to use WCF way back then,and by the time I had it all finished .Net Standard Shared Projects were released. With the rise of .Net Standard and Shared Projects you could connect directly to a MS SQLSERVER or SQLEXPRESS, etc... with ADO or Entity Framework (6 I think), but there was a big push to use Entity Framework Core, which as of the last iteration of Xamarin Forms, still worked perfectly.

Now, with security in mind, you do not want to release some consumer application on the public store, that has a clear, plain text connection string or that accesses your corporate SQLServer from the outside.  This should be common sense to any developer. But of course most companies will require the use of SonicWall VPN and Microsoft Authenticator, leveraging 2FA. However, if you are writing sideloaded apps or "ad hoc" Line-of-Business apps that ONLY RUN INTERNALLY on a company's internal network, and the application is never exposed to consumers and the devices never leave the facility, connecting to a database through a shared .Net Standard DAL is perfectly acceptable.

Use Entity Framework Core and it will generate all the classes and the context you need in the .Net Standard Shared Project. Install the relevant Nuget packages, and then run the commands via Package Manager on your dev machine so that it scaffolds in your database entity context and generates all the models youll need to access the DB. Then in your app, connect up to the context and do what you need to do via async Tasks. There is no need for another layer like a WCF service or RESTful API unless you just NEED to have that type of infrastructure.

Most companies have the security already implemented into the devices or deployment mechanisms, via MDMs, and require the users to authenticate via Active Directory on the internal network , or through a tenant in Azure, or even 2FA in some cases with or without the use of MS Authenticator.

But that being said...Be mindful of your implementations. Encrypt your credentials and dont let them float around the internal network in plain text. Make sure distribution of the devices accessing the local database is managed on some level perhaps with an MDM, make sure your app deployment is protected and follows the company's deployment protocols, and make sure your database is secure.