# Getting the setup of the project prepared with C# and MSSQL on another computer

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation, setup-project

When I want to use the setup of the project I prepared with C# and MSSQL on another computer, I get an error like this.

Calling JIT debugging instead of this dialog
See the end of this message for detailed information about.

```
***** Exception Text *****
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to the server. The server was not found or the server cannot be reached. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server allows remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Finding the Specified Server/Instance)
    location: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionDa ta, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager)
    location: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    location: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    location: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
    location: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
    location: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
    location: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
    location: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
    location: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    location: System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
    location: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
    location: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
    location: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
    location: InternetCafeAutomation.User.UserLogin(TextBox Username, TextBox Password)
    location: InternetCafeAutomation.frmUser.btnEntry_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    location: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:-1,State:0,Class:20
```

Installed Builds:

```
mscorlib
     Integrated Code Version: 4.0.0.0
     Win32 Version: 4.8.9181.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
InternetCafeAutomation
     Integrated Code Version: 1.0.0.0
     Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
     CodeBase: file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Default%20Company%20Name/SetupInternetKafe/InternetCafeAutomation.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
     Integrated Code Version: 4.0.0.0
     Win32 Version: 4.8.9181.0 built by: NET481REL1LAST_C
     CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
     Integrated Code Version: 4.0.0.0
     Win32 Version: 4.8.9214.0 built by: NET481RE
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Specify the correct connection string.

Comment: well, it tells you the issue is that it cannot connect to sql server. are you running a sql Server locally or connects to some network computer? Also, you shouldn't connect to database on Mouse Clicks, it's bad for the UI

Comment: Check if the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is running also

Comment: _error: 26 - Error Finding the Specified Server/Instance_ sounds like you have an instance name in your connection string. Is the SQL Browser service enabled, running and accessible via firewall(s) on udp/1434?

Comment: The issue is with the connection string.  You are using a username and password which may not work.  The credential of the database and the credentials your app are using are not compatible.  I would first try using SQL Server Management Studio from the same machine that is failing.  See if you can connect to server.  Check login window of SSMS and see if credentials is Windows.  Also verify the Server Name\ Instance.  If you can connect you can look at log file in the explorer under Management for any errors.  The log should show Group and User that logged in.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425