Connection string in C# on a domain
I made an application in c# and on my local computer the connection string I had was
strStringCnx = "Data Source=" + parameters[0] + "\\" + parameters[1] + " ; Initial Catalog=" + parameters[2] + " ; User ID=xxxx ; PASSWORD=xxxx";

Where:
parameters[0] is the name of the device
parameters[2] is the database
When I was going to install the application on a server I realized that the SQL installation did not specify an instance so I changed the connection string to:
strStringCnx = "Data Source=" + parameters[0] + " ; Initial Catalog=" + parameters[2] + " ; UserID=xxxx; PASSWORD=xxxx";

But when trying to open the application an error appears and this is because it could not connect to the SQL server, I tried the application on another computer that the SQL server does handle an explicit instance and no error appears.
Something important to note is that the server is on a domain, so I don't know if the connection string is different.
I have already tried connection strings for example:
strStringCnx = "Server=" + parameters[0] + " ; Database=" + parameters[2] + " ; User ID=xxxx; PASSWORD=xxxx";

SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(GetConnectionString());
builder.InitialCatalog= parameters[2];
builder.DataSource= parameters[1];
builder.UserID = "xxxx";
builder.Password = "xxxx";

strStringCnx = builder.ConnectionString;

When capturing the exception, which originates when trying to connect to the database, the message that appears is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

There are many reference documents available on how to build your connection string. I recommend consulting them and then posting if you still have difficulties. And you need to show us the values stored in your parameters.

The following may be of interest: Connection Strings, https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425 and String interpolation.

@user246821 Building a connection string with string interpolation is like building an SQL command with string interpolation.

I have searched for a lot of documentation and consulted many publications, including here on stackoverflow, but it hasn't worked for me. That's why I decided to ask. Thanks to everyone who has responded.
If I am using Visual Studio and the parameters are basically a username and password, which was created in the SQL server logins

So what values are you passing in your parameters... its important

@GSerg: According to the URL you provided Protecting Connection Information A connection string injection attack can occur when dynamic string concatenation is used to build connection strings based on user input.. The code in the OP is rather minimal and there's nothing that indicates that the values are from user input.

@JhonnatanLopez from Visual Studio there are tools to generate a connection string in two minutes and test it. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56635680/2516718 Can you see the server from your computer?


Something important to note is that the server is on a domain, so I don't know if the connection string is different.

Whether on a domain or not, SQL Server supports two authentication modes:

SQL authentication, which needs a username and password in the connection string
Integrated authentication, which does NOT allow a username or password in the connection string at all. Instead, you use Trusted_Connection=yes; or Integrated Security=true; in the connection string. This uses the existing user authentication token from your current Windows session.

Integrated authentication works with our without a domain, but is especially common in domain environments.

This is correct, but irrelevant to the question.

The problem was that it was not finding the path of the file where the connection data was saved: the name of the server and the database, therefore they were not loaded in the parameters and that is why the connection was not generated. Thank you very much to everyone who tried to help me, in part your comments led me to find the error.
