System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server
I'm just new in this sql database, Let say I have pc1 and pc2 so this pc1 is where I published the "Appointment" from vb.net with a sql database and the sql server is also from pc1 and saved to "Appt" folder then pc2 can access this by run command and type "\pc1"
But when I run the "Appointment" from pc2 and click a button to display the datagrid this message popped up

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

This is the example code in Search button:
Private Sub Searchbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Searchbtn.Click
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server=pc1\SQLEXPRESS; Database=Appointments; User Id=sa; Password=pc1")
End Sub

This is from Appointment.exe.config:
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="Appointment.My.MySettings.AppointmentsConnectionString"
  connectionString="Data Source=pc1\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Appointments;User ID=sa;Password=pc1;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

What steps should I do to access the database from pc2 and display the data in datagrid when the Search button is clicked?

You probably need to open the firewall on pc1. Usually it will be on port 1433 + 1434 for the browser service, but depends on the installation

I already did that but the problem still insist.

Try using ip and port directly then. If you did things right you wouldn't have the error so obviously you didnt

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71199793/10024425
