# SQL cannot connect through ip address C#

Tags: c#, sql, tcp, ip, sqlconnection

I was wondering if someone could help me with this problem I have?  I am not able to connect to my SQL server even though I correctly provided my IDE with the SQL server's port number and my IP address.

```
 static SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.198,49172;Initial Catalog=irradix_base;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=pass;");
```

Comment: usually a firewall prevents connections from the Lan, did you open them?

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the currently set static port of the instance? You need to set the static port to `49172` (or change your connection string to match the port being used). You need to enable Remote Connections and TCP. You need to create a firewall exception for `sqlservr.exe`

Comment: I did set the static port to 49172.  I did not create a firewall exception for sqlservr.exe though.  I will do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, I found an answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451490/how-to-identify-port-number-of-sql-server) which uses a powershell command to find the listening port, here is the code:

```
ForEach ($SQL_Proc in Get-Process | Select-Object -Property  ProcessName, Id | Where-Object {$_.ProcessName -like "*SQL*"})
{
    Get-NetTCPConnection | `
     Where-Object {$_.OwningProcess -eq $SQL_Proc.id} | `
      Select-Object -Property `
                                @{Label ="Process_Name" e={$SQL_Proc.ProcessName}}, `
                                @{Label ="Local_Address";e={$_.LocalAddress + ":" + $_.LocalPort }},  `
                                @{Label ="Remote_Address";e={$_.RemoteAddress + ":" + $_.RemotePort}}, State | `
      Format-Table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this way
Data Source=192.168.1.198,49172;Initial Catalog=EnVerifyDB;User ID=sa;Password=123456

Comment: This is not what I am asking for.  The “Initial Catalog” is to verify which database in my server that I am using.  Changing the database will not help with my problem.