# How can i see what port my sql 2000 is using?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I want to make fordward my sql port. How can i see what port my sql is using?

Should i type something in cmd ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port

Comment: I take this results: ipv6:49307 ipv4:49307 and below  ipv4:1433 ipv6:1433 what should i put in Lanport and what in public port?

Comment: Looks like SQl server is listening standard  port 1433.

Comment: Should i go in congigutation manager and delete from ipall tcpport and tcp dynamicsports?

Comment: I haven't worked with 2000 for years, not sure on it.

Comment: Tell me for 2005. Tcp/ip enable right?

Comment: Do you want go in chat?

Comment: Mine is 2008, it has dynamic ports disabled and port=1433 for all IP entries. I don not expose it externally.