# JDBC connection string for SQL Server 2014 using port number

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2014

I have installed SQL Server 2014 in Windows 10 with database port (1433) instead of a named instance with Java8. I am trying to use the below mentioned connection string format to connect.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=TEST_DATABASE;userName=user;password=user
```

But the connection fails. The SQL JDBC driver I am using is `sqljdbc42.jar`. I am able to connect successfully while trying to SQL server created using instance name instead of port. The format mentioned below works fine.

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=COMP_SYS;databaseName=NEW_DATABASE;userName=user;password=user
```

Only with DB port connection is getting failed. What am I missing.

Comment: It sounds like you still installed a named instance (COMP_SYS) on port 1433 instead of a default instance.

Comment: No. I use a VM to install the SQL server. In a separate snapshot, I installed the SQL Server with a named instance and tried to connect and it was fine. In another snapshot if I use port 1433 instead of named instance, the connection is getting failed.

Comment: What's the exact error you get?

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12297475/2144390) for ways to verify the port number that the SQL Server instance is using.