# ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:3306 - Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed in node.js i am getting error while running

Tags: node.js, sql-server

In node.js I am getting error while running index.js file:

```
var dbConfig = {  
        user: "test",  
        password: "***",  
        server: "localhost",  
        database: "hello",
        port: parseInt("3306"),
        options: {
              "enableArithAbort": true
            }
}; 
app.get("/CodList", function(_req ,_res){  
    var Sqlquery = "select * from CodeList";  
    QueryToExecuteInDatabase(_res, Sqlquery);  
});
```

How to fetch the records from dtabase using node.js?

Comment: You say you're getting an error; what *is* the error? Is your SQL Server instance really using port 3306? 3306 is the default port for MySQL, so it's an odd choice for a non-default port.

Comment: Port number is 61499 for sql connection. I ran  query to get port number:Error while connecting to database :- ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:61499 - Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

Comment: *"Port number is 61499 for sql connection"* Your connection string above says 3306, not 61499, which (like I said) is the default port for MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: how to know the portnumber for sql server?

Comment: The default port, for SQL Server, is 1433. If you aren't using the default, there are various solutions in this question: [How to find SQL Server running port?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12297475/2029983)

Comment: Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 61499]. i placed 61499 in above code. but still receiving the same error

Comment: You have said that SQL Server is listening on an IPv6 port - as opposed to IPv4 we all know and love. Depending on your network configuration `localhost` will either resolve to `127.0.0.1` (IPv4) or `0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1` (IPv6), most commonly the former. Does whatever Node library you're using for SQL Server connections actually support IPv6 connections? Will it connect if you change to `server: "::1"` or `server: "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1"` ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this way to solve this problem :

```js
    options: {
      encrypt:false
    }
    full :
    const msSqlConfig={
      server:SQL_SERVER_NAME,
      port:SQL_PORT,
      user:${SQL_USER_NAME},
      password:${SQL_PASSWORD},
      database:SQL_DB_NAME,
      options: {
          encrypt:false
      }
    }
```