# SQL Server : get client tcp port without admin user

Tags: sql-server

First, my SQL Server user didn't have sysadmin permissions, and I want to get client port like

```
SELECT client_tcp_port 
FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
```

How can I get this information with T-SQL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this answer is all need sysadmin, my dbuser is Low permissions user without sys permissions

Comment: If you're connected then your client app will know which port it's on. Why would you want to do this in TSQL?

Comment: The client drivers don't expose this information directly, so you would have to enumerate all the sockets connected to the SQL Server's IP address.  And the server could have multiple, or for in Azure SQL Database connecting from Azure be a redirection from the load balancer.

Comment: The link I provided, shows how to identify the post at the command prompt too.

Comment: In fact, all of the above methods require administrator privileges,So i changed the plan https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807068/how-to-synchronize-the-contents-of-the-system-view-to-my-own-table-in-real-time

Answer (score 1):

Either get a sysadmin to grant you the [required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) VIEW SERVER STATE permission, or provide you with a [signed stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-signing-stored-procedures-with-a-certificate?view=sql-server-ver15).