# Read port configured on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, client, port

I am working on a SQL Server database requirement.
SQL Server database is installed in a remote server system.
From a client I need to read the port configured on server.
Is it possible to do this from the client side, preferably using C++?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port) help ?

Comment: This is why you use Instance Names in connection strings. Clients will use the [SQL Server Resolution Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/mc-sqlr/1ea6e25f-bff9-4364-ba21-5dc449a601b7) to communicate with the SQL Browser service via udp/1434 on the target server to resolve the instance name to the appropriate TCP port number, then the client connects to the instance via the resolved TCP port number.

Comment: You could communicate directly with SQL Server Browser if you want. The protocol is defined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/mc-sqlr/1ea6e25f-bff9-4364-ba21-5dc449a601b7

Comment: @Charlieface Do you have any samples I could refer? I am new to this topic.

Comment: Can some one confirm if below connection string and conditions are correct? Case1: Connection string with port number, NO NEED for SQL Server Browser >>>>
CString connString("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<ip>\\InstanceName,1433;Network=DBMSSOCN;DATABASE=Name;UID=UserName;PWD=Password;"); 
 
Case2: Connection string without port number - SQL Server Browser MUST run >>>>
CString connString("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=<ip>\\InstanecName;Network=DBMSSOCN;DATABASE=Name;UID=UserName;PWD=Password;");