Py4JJavaError : The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed
first time learning pyspark, want to learn Read and Write from/to Sql Server Via JDBC
using this code
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

host = "localhost"  
database = "AdventureWorks2019"
query_table = """(
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE') custom_table"""
jdbc_url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{host}:1433;databaseName={database};integratedSecurity=true;"
driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

jdbc_driver_path = "C:/Users/~/sqljdbc_12.8/enu/jars/mssql-jdbc-12.8.1.jre8.jar"
auth_dll_path = "C:/Users/~/sqljdbc_12.8/enu/auth/x64/mssql-jdbc_auth-12.8.1.x64.dll"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master("local[*]") \
    .appName("PySpark SQL Server Connection") \
    .config("spark.jars", jdbc_driver_path) \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", jdbc_driver_path) \
    .config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", f"-Djava.library.path={auth_dll_path}") \
    .getOrCreate()


but when i run this code
# Read from SQL Server
df_1 = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", jdbc_url) \
    .option("dbtable", query_table) \
    .option("driver", driver) \
    .load()

i got an error during load()
"name": "Py4JJavaError",
"message": "An error occurred while calling o40.load: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: \"Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.

i added new rule in firewall inbound, i checked the manager protocols its enabled, trying run telnet with my servername and the result is connect failed. also i check ERRORLOG from anyone had an idea how to fix this?

have you tried to connect via SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)?

It doesn't seem like your sql server is running on port 1433. How does it looks when you click on TCP/IP and look under the ports? You can also try running: exec xp_readerrorlog 0, 1, N'Server is listening on' see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297475/how-to-find-sql-server-running-port

im using SQL Server Management Studio

when i open the TCP/IP in SQL Server manager ip1,ip2,ip3 all of them using TCP Port 1433

What did the output of the above command said?
