# "CREATE DATABASE permission denied" error

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

I have installed SQL SERVER 2008 R2 on my system with Windows XP operating system installed.

Whenever I try to create a new database it displays an error:

```
CREATE DATABASE PERMISSION DENIED IN DATABASE 'master'.(Microsoft SQL Server, Error:262)
```

Comment: Are you a member of the sysadmin role?

Comment: no,even i don't know how to grant this permission.

Comment: When you installed it, there was a page where you specified who should be sys admins for the instance. It doesn't sound like you used the right options (one of them was to `Add Current User`) (unless this is Express)

Comment: @CodeUnderflow - Do you have the password for the 'sa' user? This would have been something configured when you installed SQL Server with SQL Authentication mode.

Answer (score 4):

When you start SQL server management studio use 'sa' user and not Windows-User. Looks like Windows-user does not have permission.

Answer (score 3):

Try to grant the user your loged in the [CREATE ANY DATABASE Permission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) then try again.
Take a look at the [documentation about creating a new Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186312%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Comment: if that user is unable to grant permission to the user I have logged in then?

Comment: You need to log in with the Admin user to grant this User the needed Permission, this depends on the Option you choosed when you installed the Server, you can use a Windows authentication or a SQL Server one where you provide the Username and Password, this User should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click and run "SQL Server Management Studio" as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Cause of this error is insufficient permission. Give the user "dbcreater" role [image: check dbcreater role]

Comment: May I ask about how to go this Screen? Thanks.

Comment: Server->Security->Logins and choose your user with right click.

Answer (score 1):

Check it:
SqlSever>>Security>>Logins>>BUILTIN\Users rightClick -->Properties
-->Server Roles
...select sysadimn

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation where you have public/view only access to a SQL database you should consider the following:

1. Do you have an alternate login or the sa user login credentials? If so, try this first and, if necessary, grant your other login sufficient privileges via the Security/Logins/.. section of your database in the Object Explorer panel ([see Ahmet Arslan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32747886/2216041)).
2. If you have account access to another Windows user who has access via Windows Authentication, try running ssms.exe as the other user via the "runas" command. Full details and explanation [here in the answer from SqlRyan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099401/2216041).
3. If you have old databases from a previous Windows installation that had been configured with Windows Authentication (and you do not have/remember the sa account credentials). In this situation, you can recreate your past user account from your previous Windows installation. Be sure this new account has the same Domain and Username as your previous account. Login via the recreated account, and give your current (or "real") user account sufficient permissions (see #1. above). Once you confirm that you have restored access, you can then delete the recreated user account.

Answer (score 0):

With this problem, I noticed I was connected using **Windows Authentication**. I then disconnected and used **SQL Server Authentication**. It is good now.

Comment: First time user. when I do SQL Server Authentication it is asking username and password. Any idea what is the default username/password?

Comment: @williamcage 
SQL Server 2008/R2 Express
User:  sa
Password:   [blank password - leave field empty to connect]

SQL Server 201x Express
User:  sa
Password: Password123


SQL Server 20xx Web or Standard
User: sa
Password:   will be the same as your administrator or root user password at the time the VDS was provisioned.

Answer (score 0):

first you will login on windows authentication
then you will click on login (sa) properties and server role check in db creater  then ok click then error is solved and after login within sa and  create a database