# Unable to create new DataBase in MS Sql Management Studios

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I do not remember the serverauthentication password, so I am using windows authentication. I am not able to do anything.

[image]

Comment: you should try and do some research on Google. An error 262 appears to be related to permission to create a database. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14625682/create-database-permission-denied-error

Comment: In case of emergency: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

Comment: I already went through those links. But I cant grant permission. I don have permission to grant permission. I am logged in as Admin though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fulfill the following requirements:

1. you must be a member of Local Administrators group on the computer where the SQL Server is running.
2. The SQL Server service must be run under the LocalSystem account.

In this case, when connecting using Windows Authentication, you can check if you have any permissions (check the *`Logins`* sub-section of the **`Security`** section in the SSMS. If the **`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`** is shown there, you can add the needed database. Otherwise you need to bethink the sysadmin login & password.