# SQL Server login with different domain (Intellij Idea)

Tags: sql-server, intellij-idea, windows-authentication

I'd like to connect to a remote MS SQL server. I have to login with windows authentication but with a different domain like I'm authenticated on my local computer.
How can I do that? Where can I enter the domain of the server?

I've already tried to use standard autentication with username: SERVERDOMAIN\USERNAME but it didn't work.

I'm using Idea version 2016.1.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `Windows authentication` connecting from another non-trusted domain.

Your choises are:

- join your pc into the same domain
- use SQL Server authentication
- use only the **same accounts with the same passwords** in case of
  different domains

Comment: With SQL Server Management Studio it is possible to connect to a remote server and authenticate with another domain like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849149/connect-different-windows-user-in-sql-server-management-studio-2005-or-later
Is something similar prossible with Intellij Idea?

Comment: @eztam The feature you linked is an OS feature, not a SSMS feature. It may or may not work with your app (development environment?). Why ask if it works; you can try it yourself.

Comment: I've tried it already without success. So I thought, there might be eventually another similar way to do that.